# Geeks for geeks Maximum water Between two building

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve a problem in GeeksClasses and I am having an issue with my submission. My code works but they are saying Your program took more time than expected.Time Limit Exceeded
Expected Time Limit < 3.448sec
Hint : Please optimize your code and submit again.

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-water-between-two-buildings/1/?track=SPCF-Searching&batchId=154

## Problem statement:

Given an integer array height of size N which represents the heights of N buildings, the task is to delete N-2 buildings such that the water that can be trapped between the remaining two building is maximum. Please note that the total water trapped between two buildings is gap between them (number of buildings removed) multiplied by height of the smaller building.

## Input Format:

The first line of input contains T denoting the number of testcases. T testcases follow. Each testcase contains two lines of input. The first line contains N denoting the number of elements in the array. The second line contains the elements of the array.

## Output Format:

For each testcase, in a new line, print the maximum amount of water that can be stored between any two buildings after you remove n-2 buildings.

## Here is my Code:

```
def maxWater(height, n): 
    maximum = 0;  
  
    # Check all possible pairs of buildings  
    for i in range(n - 1) : 
        for j in range(i + 1, n) : 
            current = min(height[i],  
                          height[j]) * (j - i - 1);  
  
            # Maximum so far  
            maximum = max(maximum, current);  
              
    return maximum;
```

Comment: add the sample input and expected output

Comment: what is             current = min(height[i],  
                          height[j]) * (j - i - 1);   suposed to do? (shouldn't it be j-i as that is the number of buildings removed/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you've written a quadratic time solution (`O(n^2)`) while the optimal solution to this problem is linear (`O(n)`).

**Hint:** the volume of water that can be trapped between 2 buildings is dependent on the height of the shorter of the 2 buildings.

Answer (score 1):

First, dont need to compare a building with the next one, as that will remove 0 buildings and store 0 water.
Second, you only need to try and find a max on the next building on the list, if it is taller than the previous one you tried, as only a taller building can store more water than the previous one because it will remove one less building:

```
def maxWater(height, n):
    max_checked_height = 0

    maximum = 0;  

    # Check all possible pairs of buildings

    for i in range(0, n):
        max_checked_height = max(height[i], max_checked_height)
        # now compare with the rest of buildings, only if it is taller than any already compared
        if height[i] >= max_checked_height:
            for j in range(i+2, n-2):
                removed_building = j-i
                stored_water = removed_buildings * (min(height[i], height[j])
                maximum = max(stored_water, maximum) 

    return maximum
```

Something like this, there are other optimization solutions, like sorting by height etc, but that would be too much, another approach would be to create 2 vectors of min height and buildings removed, then all you have to do is return the max of the cross product of those 2 vectors, but will leave that for you

Edit: changed the second var to go from i to i-2 so that you dont get indexerrors